# My Sprite Rectangle moves, but my sprite doesn't

Tags: c#, xna-4.0, sprites, spritebatch

Here's the issue, When I build, everything loads fine, everything works, but then, when you enter the game, the sprite is there. However, The sprite does not move, the sprite RECTANGLE does. Meaning that, if I used my arrow keys to move the "sprite", as I defined them in the update method of my class, the rectangle would move freely, and cut off parts of the sprite. If I moved it the right far enough, the rectangle would leave the sprite, and the sprite will disappear.

Here's a picture of what it looks like:

[image: http://www.flickr.com/photos/79305580@N06/8749802527/in/photostream]

and another when I use my arrow keys to move:

[image: http://www.flickr.com/photos/79305580@N06/8749802517/in/photostream/]

Here is the code from my sprite class:

```
class Player : Sprite
{
    const string PLAYER_ASSETNAME = "CharacterLeft";
    const int START_POSITION_X = 125;
    const int START_POSITION_Y = 245;
    const int WIZARD_SPEED = 160;
    const int MOVE_UP = -1;
    const int MOVE_DOWN = 1;
    const int MOVE_LEFT = -1;
    const int MOVE_RIGHT = 1;

    enum State
    {
        Walking
    }
    State mCurrentState = State.Walking;

    Vector2 mDirection = Vector2.Zero;
    Vector2 mSpeed = Vector2.Zero;

    KeyboardState mPreviousKeyboardState;

    public void LoadContent(ContentManager theContentManager)
    {
        Position = new Vector2(START_POSITION_X, START_POSITION_Y);
        base.LoadContent(theContentManager, PLAYER_ASSETNAME);
    }

    public void Update(GameTime theGameTime)
    {
        KeyboardState aCurrentKeyboardState = Keyboard.GetState();

        UpdateMovement(aCurrentKeyboardState);

        mPreviousKeyboardState = aCurrentKeyboardState;

        base.Update(theGameTime, mSpeed, mDirection);
    }
    private void UpdateMovement(KeyboardState aCurrentKeyboardState)
    {
        if (mCurrentState == State.Walking)
        {
            mSpeed = Vector2.Zero;
            mDirection = Vector2.Zero;

            if (aCurrentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left) == true)
            {
                mSpeed.X = WIZARD_SPEED;
                mDirection.X = MOVE_LEFT;
            }
            else if (aCurrentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Right) == true)
            {
                mSpeed.X = WIZARD_SPEED;
                mDirection.X = MOVE_RIGHT;
            }

            if (aCurrentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up) == true)
            {
                mSpeed.Y = WIZARD_SPEED;
                mDirection.Y = MOVE_UP;
            }
            else if (aCurrentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Down) == true)
            {
                mSpeed.Y = WIZARD_SPEED;
                mDirection.Y = MOVE_DOWN;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

}

and here's the code to my main sprite class:

```
class Sprite
{
    //The asset name for the Sprite's Texture
    public string AssetName;

    //The Size of the Sprite (with scale applied)
    public Rectangle Size;

    //The amount to increase/decrease the size of the original sprite. 
    private float mScale = 1.0f;

    //The current position of the Sprite
    public Vector2 Position = new Vector2(0, 0);

    //The texture object used when drawing the sprite
    private Texture2D mSpriteTexture;

    //The player Rectangle
    private Rectangle SpriteRect; 

    //Load the texture for the sprite using the Content Pipeline
    public void LoadContent(ContentManager theContentManager, string theAssetName)
    {
        mSpriteTexture = theContentManager.Load<Texture2D>(theAssetName);
        AssetName = theAssetName;
        Size = new Rectangle(0, 0, (int)(mSpriteTexture.Width * mScale), (int)(mSpriteTexture.Height * mScale));
    }

    //Draw the sprite to the screen
    public void Draw(SpriteBatch theSpriteBatch)
    {
        SpriteRect = new Rectangle((int)Position.X, (int)Position.Y, mSpriteTexture.Width, mSpriteTexture.Height);
        theSpriteBatch.Draw(mSpriteTexture, Position,SpriteRect, Color.White, 0.0f, Vector2.UnitX, 1f, SpriteEffects.None, 0);
    }

    public void Update(GameTime theGameTime, Vector2 theSpeed, Vector2 theDirection)
    {
        Position += theDirection * theSpeed * (float)theGameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
    }

    //When the scale is modified throught he property, the Size of the 
    //sprite is recalculated with the new scale applied.
    public float Scale
    {
        get { return mScale; }
        set
        {
            mScale = value;
            //Recalculate the Size of the Sprite with the new scale
            Size = new Rectangle(0, 0, (int)(mSpriteTexture.Width * Scale), (int)(mSpriteTexture.Height * Scale));
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: You'd have to include some *small* code snippets if you want better help with this. How you're creating/drawing/moving. As minimal as possible.

Comment: Added them, just now.

Comment: No one? Any help please?

Answer (score 2):

In the [overload of `SpriteBatch.Draw` that you are using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff433988.aspx), which you call like so:

```
SpriteRect = new Rectangle((int)Position.X, (int)Position.Y, 
    mSpriteTexture.Width, mSpriteTexture.Height);
theSpriteBatch.Draw(mSpriteTexture, Position,SpriteRect, Color.White, 0.0f,
    Vector2.UnitX, 1f, SpriteEffects.None, 0);
```

You are passing `SpriteRect` into the method parameter which defines the sprite's source rectangle.  Here's the method signature.

```
public void Draw (
    Texture2D texture,
    Vector2 position,
    Nullable<Rectangle> sourceRectangle,
    Color color,
    float rotation,
    Vector2 origin,
    float scale,
    SpriteEffects effects,
    float layerDepth
)
```

Also from that linked MSDN documentation:

> *sourceRectangle*
>
> Type: Nullable<Rectangle>
>   A rectangle that specifies (in texels) the source texels from a texture. Use **null** to draw the entire texture.

So when your sprite's position changes, the drawn texture is a different region of your asset.  That is the source of your symptoms.

You need to change one or both of those lines to the following:

```
// (this Rectangle SpriteRect doesn't need to update!)
SpriteRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, mSpriteTexture.Width, mSpriteTexture.Height);
// (Or even exist!)
theSpriteBatch.Draw(mSpriteTexture, Position, null, Color.White, 0.0f, 
    Vector2.UnitX, 1f, SpriteEffects.None, 0);
```